# Handlebars compiling to script and not to body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, handlebars.js

So, I'm trying to render a template from an external file, and when I render it, it "works," just that it sends the script, not the actual script contents to the target.

I tried using the jquery .html() function to grab the inside contents of the script, but all I get is "undefined"

This is the body content:

```html
<div id="target"></div>

    <script>
        var context = {"name": "Test"};
        $.get('template.handlebars', function (data) {
                var templateScript = Handlebars.compile(data);
                var html = templateScript(context);

                $(document.body).append(html);
        }, 'html')
    </script>
```

What I get is this:

```html
<div id="target"></div>
<script>blah blah blah</script>
<script type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="template">
    <h1>Test</h1>
</script>
```

Instead of

```html
<div id="target">
    <h1>Test</h1>
</div>
```

In response to someone's question:
Doing "body" instead of document.body has the same effect. The contents of the template document are:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="template">
    <h1>{{ name }}</h1>
</script>
```

Comment: Did you include the jquery library?

Comment: Yes I did I did include it

Comment: Does $("body") have the same effect? Also, could you post the contents of the template file too.

Comment: So, in your scenario, you have the handlebars template in a separate file –– which is not a HTML file, try removing the script tag. According to the handlebars docs, they want you to include the script tags for shielding from HTML parser, but in your case that should not be a problem. That should solve it.

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario, you have the handlebars template in a separate file –– which is not a HTML file, so you should try removing the script tag. According to the handlebars docs, they want you to include the script tags for shielding from HTML parser, but in your case that should not be a problem.

Next your jQuery `$(document.body).append(html);` is selecting the document body and appending the resulting HTML snippet.

To achieve the:

```
<div id="target">
      <h1>Test</h1>
</div>
```

you'll have to select the `target` div. Doing a `$("#target").html(html);` should solve that issue.

I've created a sample to simulate your scenario, hope this gives more insight.

**HTML file contents:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
        <title>Document</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.1.2/handlebars.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="target"></div>

        <script>
            var context = { name: "Test" };
            $.get(
                "template.handlebars",
                function(data) {
                    var templateScript = Handlebars.compile(data);
                    var html = templateScript(context);

                    // $(document.body).append(html);
                    $("#target").html(html);
                },
                "html"
            );
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Handlebars template file contents:**

`template.handlebars`

```html
<h1>{{ name }}</h1>
```

**References**

1. https://handlebarsjs.com/